# Call Service from Session_Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, autofac, unit-of-work

I have an `AuditService` I created that looks like:

```
public interface IAuditService
{
    void Log(int userId, string obj, string action, string details);
}
```

In my controllers I can call the service like this:

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IAuditService _auditService;

    public AccountController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IAuditService auditService) : base(unitOfWork)
    {
       ...
        _auditService = auditService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UserProfile(ProfileViewModel vm)
    {
        ...
        _auditService.Log(CurrentUser.UserId,"Account", "Edit", "details");
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I need to log when users sign in.  In the Global.asax file I have a Session_start() method that gets the logged in user.  I need to be able to call the `AuditService` from here also.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var sid = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.User.ToString();

            using (var context = new SqlContext())
            {
                SystemUser user = context.SystemUsers.Where(u => u.UserSid == sid).FirstOrDefault();

                if (user != null)
                {
                    user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on what I should try?  I attempted something like the few lines below, but I get an `invalid argument` error.

```
AuditService audit = new AuditService(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAuditService>().Log);
audit.Log(user.UserId, "Account", "Login", "Successfull login");
```

Comment: Since you're already using `autofac`, why not simply do `IAuditService audit = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAuditService>();`?

Comment: I knew it had to be simple!  If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Autofac as your dependency resolver, you can get a reference to the implementation of `IAuditService` using:

```
IAuditService audit = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAuditService>();
```

Then call its methods:

```
audit.Log(user.UserId, "Account", "Login", "Successfull login");
```

See [DependencyResolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dependencyresolver%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)